# SCSS - Correct way to merge similar groups (but not the same)

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to merge two similar groups in SCSS.
Here's the current css:

```
  .elemType1,
  .elemType2,
  .elemType3,
  .elemType4 {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #fff;
  }

  .elemType1,
  .elemType2,
  .elemType3 {
    font-size: 10px;
    max-width: 1110px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 300px;
  }
```

As you can see, both groups are near-identical except the first also has .elemType4. How should I merge these to reduce repetition, or is this not possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sass you could write it like so:

```
.elemType4 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
}

.elemType1,
.elemType2,
.elemType3 {
  @extend .elemType4;
  font-size: 10px;
  max-width: 1110px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

see here: http://sass-lang.com/guide, -> "Extend/Inheritance"

Will turn into (CSS)

```
.elemType4 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
}

.elemType1,
.elemType2,
.elemType3 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  max-width: 1110px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have other classes starting with `elemType` you can shorten that style like so

```
  [class^="elemType"] {
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     background: #fff;

     &:not(.elemType4) {
        font-size: 10px;
        max-width: 1110px;
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 300px;
     }
  }
```

Codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaYQRO